# How do I create DataGridViewComboBoxColumn that has a grid-like drop down?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am in need of a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn that displays a multi-column grid drop down, similar to the one described [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/multicolumncombo.aspx).  Basically, I need to override the DropDown event of the underlying ComboBox.  The example at the bottom of [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxeditingcontrol.aspx) shows how I can add event handlers.  But, I need to override the showing of the drop down.  I'm guessing I need to create my own ComboBox class but how do I connect that with a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn?  Has anyone done something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding the following on MSDN that outlines how to create a custom DataGridView column.  This includes creating a cell type, a column type, and an Editing control type.  I ended up using a ListView control inside a form with no borders as my drop down grid.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730881(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

[This looks like a winner](http://www.xmlfox.com/datagrid_combobox.htm)

.NET datagrid is a graphical user interface component that presents a tabular view of data. .NET datagrid supports the following common interface features:

- Clicking a column header to implement grid sorting
- Dragging column headers to change their size
- In-cell editing of shown data
- Row and column separators, and alternating row background colors

Datagrid's cells can be presented as some different control types (textbox, button, date/time picker etc.) within datagrid interface layout. However much important control is combobox that could be placed in datagrid...